# Mail not sending in laravel 5 from an ajax post request

Tags: php, ajax, email, laravel-5

I am working on forgot password functionality in my laravel 5.0 application. I am asking user to enter registered email and submit(post method) this form works on jquery ajax post request. After getting email from request i am checking it in db whether it exist or not. if exist i am updating new password, if not sending an error message upto this every this is fine. Now i am trying to send email with new password to the user, it is not working. Password is updating but email not sending.Find my controller code below

```
public function forgot_pass(Request $request){

        $email = $request->input('femail');
        $data = ['email' => $email];

        $user = Myuser::where($data)->count();

        if($user == 0){
            return response()->json(['status' => 'Invalid']);
        }
        else{

            $user_details = Myuser::where($data)->get()->first();

            $new_pass = $this->generateRandomString();

            $md5_pass = md5("EEE".$new_pass);

            $status = Myuser::where('email', $email)
                ->update(['pass' => $md5_pass]);

                if($status){

                    $mail_data = ['name' => $user_details->name, 'new_pass' => $new_pass];

                    Mail::send('emails.newpassword', $mail_data, function($message)
                    {
                        $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

                        $message->to($email);

                    });

                    return response()->json(['status' => 'Invalid']);
                }

        }

    }
```

Actually mail is working if i used `$message->to('sometest@testmail.com');` instead of `$message->to($email);`. Below is the error i am getting.
[image]

Feeling strange why `$email` causing error.

Comment: You have wrong method for calling url in routes.

Comment: @Autista_z What wrong method ? i didn't get u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the `$email` to the anonymous function

```
Mail::send('emails.newpassword', $mail_data, function($message) use ($email) {
...
});
```